# Convert binary strings into decimal

Tags: text-processing, sed, scripting, numeric-data

I want to process with a bash script a text file that looks like this:

```
ADD    $05  $05  $05
SUBI   $06  $06  00011
MUL    $07  $07  $07
JSR    011101
```

taking the binary numbers (that are always longer than 4 bits) and converting them into their decimal representation.

For the previous example, this is the file I want to end up with:

```
ADD    $05  $05  $05
SUBI   $06  $06  3
MUL    $07  $07  $07
JSR    29
```

I have been exploring `tr` and `sed`, but I think they don't let me work with the matched pattern (to convert it) before the replacement. What approach can I take?

EDIT:
with the suggestion of  @DopeGothi, and given that I have at most one binary number per line, I can create a temporary file with all the decimal versions of the binary numbers. The issue is that now I need to intercalate them:

*Every time I find a binary number in the first file, I replace with the corresponding number in the file with decimals.*

Comment: As a start, you can use this to extract and convert the binary numbers:  `| grep -oE '[01]+' | awk '{print "ibase=2;obase=A;"$1}' | bc`.  Bear in mind that this has no way of distinguishing whether `10` is decimal, binary, octal, hexadecimal, or any other base.

Comment: but with that grep I am going to lose the rest of the content, no? I am going to read about awk, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant way using Perl's `pack` and `unpack`, but using a combination of string manipulation and `oct`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\b[01]+\b/oct "0b" . $&/ge' file
ADD    $05  $05  $05
SUBI   $06  $06  3
MUL    $07  $07  $07
JSR    29
```

See [Converting Binary, Octal, and Hexadecimal Numbers](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/cook/ch02_16.htm)

Comment: this is black magic, thank you a lot... you made me love Perl.

Answer (score 2):

Try this small `bash` script:

```
while read -a INP; do for i in ${INP[@]}; do [[ "$i" =~ [^10] ]] || i=$((2#$i));  printf "%s\t" "$i" ; done; printf "\n"; done < file3
ADD     $05     $05     $05 
SUBI    $06     $06     3   
MUL     $07     $07     $07 
JSR     29
```

May benefit from some polishing. It reads the file's lines into an array, tests if its elements contain binary digits (0 and 1) only, uses "arithmetic evaluation" with the base 2 `2#` prefix if yes, before it prints